# Error installing cocoapods: drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210

Tags: ruby, react-native, rubygems

I want to develop a project with react native Cli. I read the react native documentation. I should install cocoapods.

But when I write `sudo gem install cocoapods`, the terminal returns

```
Error installing cocoapods:
    The last version of drb (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.0.5. Try installing it with `gem install drb -v 2.0.5` and then running the current command again
    drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
```

I couldn't update ruby. When I write `rvm install 2.7.6` a different error is returned. What should I do?

Answer (score 51):

if you are using macOS, How about using homebrew than gem?
I had exactly same problem, so I tried to install it using homebrew

`brew install cocoapods`

My problem was clearly resolved!

Comment: My problem was clearly resolved too. Thanks for the solution

Comment: The solution is working perfectly in my M2 Pro. Thank you so much.

Comment: How exactly does this solve the problem? Does it install a different version than the ruby gems installation tool, by default?

Comment: "Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!" on my M1 Pro

Comment: command not found: brew
Getting this error on installing with brew

Answer (score 16):

If you encounter an error stating that CocoaPods downloader requires Ruby version >= 2.7.4, you can update your Ruby version using a Ruby version manager like `rbenv`. Follow these steps:

1. Install rbenv: If you don’t have rbenv installed, you can install it
   using a package manager like Homebrew. Open Terminal and run:

```
brew install rbenv
```

2. Add the following lines to your shell profile file (.bash_profile, .zshrc, etc.). You can get this files from Macintosh HD/ Users/username and search for hidden files `command + shift + .`
   edit:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

3. Restart your Terminal .
4. Install Ruby 2.7.4. Run the following command:

```
rbenv install 2.7.4
```

5. This will download and install Ruby 2.7.4. Restart your terminal.
6. Set Ruby 2.7.4 as the global version for your system:

```
rbenv global 2.7.4
```

7. Verify Ruby version: Ensure that Ruby 2.7.4 is now the active version:

```
ruby -v
```

8. Try installing CocoaPods again

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

This should resolve the issue, and you should be able to use CocoaPods without any problems.

Comment: Formatting of export breaks it.
Needs to be:
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"<br/>
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

Comment: I missed to mention the new-line <br/> in second step. Thanks  @TasosZervos for rectifying errors.

Answer (score 7):

If you read the error message carefully, you may find a solution within the error message.

```
sudo gem install drb -v 2.0.5
```

You can try this line in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

First way:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Second way:

```html
brew update
brew install ruby

# If you use bash
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile 

# If you use ZSH:
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zprofile

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have to use sudo to install it. Just run:

```
brew install cocoapods
```

After succesful installation, run:

```
brew link cocoapods
```

This should work.

However, if you get an error like this: "Error: Could not symlink bin/xcodeproj, Target /usr/local/bin/xcodeproj already exists", you can overwrite it using:

```
brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo gem install cocoapods
2. got error with drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0
3. You need install ruby
4. sudo gem install drb -v 2.0.6
5. Again install sudo gem install cocoapods
6. sudo gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.7
7. Again install sudo gem install cocoapods
8. check with your pod --version
   Your problem solved.